# How do you execute a built in gradle task in a doFirst/doLast closure?

Tags: testing, task, gradle

I don't know if I'm not doing this right or if i have to handle builtin gradle tasks differently but i have a test task that i defined like this

```
task testNGTests(type: Test) {
     useTestNG()
}
```

and am trying to use it in a doFirst closure like this

```
task taskA {
  doFirst {
        testNGTests.execute()
   }
}
```

but it does not work for some reason, i have also tried

```
testNGTests.executeTests()
```

but that did not work either. Is there a special way that I have to handle the built in test task?

I am using gradle version 0.9.2

Comment: Tasks do not support `execute()` calls.  Only closures (i.e. method defs) do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Executing a task from another task isn't (and never was) officially supported. Try to use task dependencies instead, e.g. `taskA.dependsOn(testNGTests)`.

Comment: But there's no way to support ordering if there are multiple dependencies, right? How would I get around this?

Comment: Please give a concrete example. `taskA.dependsOn(taskB, taskC)` is shorthand for `taskA.dependsOn(taskB); taskA.dependsOn(taskC)`. But you can of course do `taskA.dependsOn(taskB); taskB.dependsOn(taskC)`.

Comment: so if i have a `taskA (dependsOn: taskB, taskC)` gradle will run taskC taskB and then taskA, but if I have `taskA(dependsOn: taskC, taskB)` gradle still runs it in the order of taskB, taskC, taskA, the dependencies are being ordered alphabetically which seems a bit odd

Comment: In your examples, the order between taskB and taskC is _undefined_ and Gradle is free to choose any order.

Comment: But if i do not always want taskB to depend on taskC, say for example sometimes I want taskB to execute alone  or have another step between taskC and taskB, is there no way to do that? It seems somewhat counter intuitive that gradle will go ahead and pick whatever order it feels like considering that the dependsOn syntax is array based so the order feels implied.

Comment: It feels counter-intuitive because you are used to this behavior from Ant. Gradle doesn't currently have soft dependencies like Ant has.

Comment: Then how can you call tasks conditionally from methods?

Answer (score 8):

I found a workaround to do this. In my scenario I have a task that reads an user input and depending on his anwser I need to create a EAR with different configurations. I used a task of type  [GradleBuild](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/GradleBuild.html). Here is the code:

```
task createEar() << {   
    def wichTypeOfEar = System.console().readLine("Which EAR?? (a, b)\n")    
    if(wichTypeOfEar == 'a'){
        tasks.earA.execute()
    }else{
        tasks.earB.execute()
    }    
}

task earA(type: GradleBuild) {
    doFirst{
       // Here I can do some stuffs related to ear A
    }
    tasks = ['ear']
}

task earB(type: GradleBuild) {
    doFirst{
       // Here I can do some stuffs related to ear B
    }
    tasks = ['ear']
}

ear {
   //Here is the common built in EAR task from 'ear' plugin
}
```

In you case you could do the following:

```
task testNGTests(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()    
}

task testNGTestsWrapper(type: GradleBuild){
    tasks = ['testNGTests']
}

task taskA {
    doFirst {
    testNGTestsWrapper.execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to prepend `tasks.` before executing?