# Call another task from a task in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using Gradle. I have two tasks: "a" and "b". I want task "a" to call task "b". How can I do this?

```
task b(type: Exec) {
    description "Task B"
    commandLine 'echo', 'task-b'
}

task a(type: Exec) {
    description "Task A"
    commandLine 'echo', 'task-a'
    // TODO: run task b
}
```

In Ant this is a piece of cake:

```
<target name="a">
    <echo message="task-a"/>
    <antcall target="b"/>
</target>
<target name="b">
    <echo message="task-b"/>
</target>
```

The first method I tried is using the "dependsOn" feature. However this is not ideal as we would need to think of all the tasks in reverse and also has several other issues (like running a task when a condition is satisfied).

Another method I tried is:

```
b.mustRunAfter(a)
```

However this only works if I run the gradle tasks like so:

```
gradle -q a b
```

Which is also not ideal.

Is there anyway to simply just call another task from an existing task?

Comment: what about finalizer tasks? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks

Comment: This answer here is pretty good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868051/491553

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As suggested one method would be to add a finalizer for the task

```
task beta << {
    println 'Hello from beta'
}

task alpha << {
    println "Hello from alpha"
}

// some condition
if (project.hasProperty("doBeta")) {
    alpha.finalizedBy beta
}
```

Then we can execute the other task if needed.  As for executing tasks from another tasks you cannot do that.  Task declaration is declarative not imperative.  So a task can depend on another task but they cannot execute another task.

```
$ gradle -q alpha
Hello from alpha
$ gradle -q alpha -PdoBeta
Hello from alpha
Hello from beta
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use

```
a.dependsOn 'b'
```

Or

```
a.dependsOn b
```

Or

```
task a(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'b') { ... }
```

etc

See [adding dependencies to tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks)

Answer (score 22):

To summarize and combine the answers from @JBirdVegas and @lance-java, using non-deprecated `doLast` instead of leftShift (`<<`):

```
task beta {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello from beta'
    }
}

task alpha {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello from alpha'
    }
}

// some condition
if (project.hasProperty('doBeta')) {
    alpha.finalizedBy beta // run 'beta' after 'alpha'
    // or
    // alpha.dependsOn beta // run 'beta' before 'alpha'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine but providing a warning as Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.

[image: enter imagGradleription here]

I am using gradle version 4.7. So it means some of the features you have added in the build.gradle will not work as it is in gradle 5.0.

Run the Gradle build with a command line argument --warning-mode=all to see what exactly the deprecated features are.

It will give you a detailed description of found issues with links to the Gradle docs for instructions how to fix your build.