# Gradle: Iterate over test dir and perform muiltiple tasks in each dir

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to iterate over my `test/` dir which contains a subfolder for every testcase and then want to perform different tasks in each subfolder.

This does not work:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.eerohele.saxon-gradle' version '0.3.0'
}

task lessCompile {
  description 'compile less to css'
  ...
}

task runAllTests(dependsOn: lessCompile) {
  description 'runs all tests'

  doLast {
    new File(testFolder).eachDir() { testcase->
      println testcase

      // transform test_dev.xml to test_dev_prep.xml
      xslt {
        input file(testcase + '/test_dev.xml')
        stylesheet file('xslt/prepare.xsl')
        output file(testcase + '/test_dev_prep.xml')
      }

      exec {
        workingDir '.'
        commandLine 'cmd', "/c sys-command $testcase -param ..."
      }

      javaexec {
        classpath = buildscript.configurations.classpath
        main = '.....'
        args = ['-headless', '-f1', "$testcase/file1" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `runAllTests` task fails because the `xslt` task cannot be executed inside the `doLast` closure ([issue](https://github.com/eerohele/saxon-gradle/issues/8)) because calling tasks from `doFirst`/`doLast` never was officially supported ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979582/how-do-you-execute-a-built-in-gradle-task-in-a-dofirst-dolast-closure)).

However, what is the official way then to iterate over dirs, perform tests and pass arguments to those tasks.

And don't come with `dependsOn`, this does not work for my case. I only use it here in this example to illustrate that `lessCompile` is a static task in contrary to the other tasks I try to call from within the `doLast` block.

Comment: Gradle tasks can only be executed once in a build. So you can either use one task (and one execution) for all directories or a single task for each directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, tasks are **never** executed **inside** other tasks or their `doFirst`/`doLast` closures.

The topic of the [StackOverflow question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979582/how-do-you-execute-a-built-in-gradle-task-in-a-dofirst-dolast-closure) is about calling `execute` directly on a task, which you should **never** do, because it may break the task system of Gradle. What you really want to do is calling a method that does exactly the same thing as a specific task, but that is simply not possible.

Gradle provides the methods [`copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#copy(groovy.lang.Closure)), [`delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#delete(org.gradle.api.Action)), [`exec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec(groovy.lang.Closure)) and [`javaexec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#javaexec(groovy.lang.Closure)), but none of those have anything to do with tasks, even if they may provide the same interface for configuration. In your current example, there are only two tasks: `lessCompile` and `runAllTests`.

So, to do something in Gradle for multiple directories and with differing configuration (like input and output files), you need to create a new task for each directory:

```
task lessCompile() { /* configure lessCompile task */ }

task runAllTests() {
    file('test').eachDir { testcase ->
        dependsOn (tasks.create([name: "$testcase.name|javaexec", type: JavaExec], {
            // configure javaexec task
        }).dependsOn (tasks.create([name: "$testcase.name|exec", type: Exec], {
            // configure exec task
        }).dependsOn (tasks.create([name: "$testcase.name|xslt", type: SaxonXsltTask], {
            // configure xslt task
        }).dependsOn (lessCompile))))
    }
}
```

For a folder `test` with the subfolders `test1` and `test2` this will end up executing the following tasks for `gradle runAllTests`:

```
:lessCompile
:test1|xslt
:test1|exec
:test1|javaexec
:test2|xslt
:test2|exec
:test2|javaexec
:runAllTests
```

It may be confusing, that the task definitions appear in the opposite order of their execution, but this is caused by the `dependsOn` chain. You may use `finalizedBy` instead, but I think these are cases of tasks that need to be done **before** other tasks, instead of tasks that need to be done **after** other tasks.